# How to format .schema output with SQLite3?

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, sqlite, database-schema

I created some sqlite tables schema using python.

When I use the sqlite3 client and issue the `.schema` command, I can see the output is pre-formated as in the SQL source file I used as argument for the `executescript()` function.

Is there any method I could use to format the outputof the `.schema` command?

Comment: "SQL the way it should be" What does this mean?

Comment: Indented, keywords uppercase… This is purely for cosmetic purpose. I know that the best thing I can do is nicely format the SQL myself but I also ask this for the case where the tables declaration were badly formatted and I still want to have a nicely formatted output when I issue the _.schema_ command.

Comment: Are you asking us for code that reformats the SQL, or for some library or tool?

Comment: I wonder if there is any way to do it directly inside the sqlite3 client, but I'm also interested in any tools or library (python3) to do so.

Answer (score 16):

In the latest version ( 3.13.0 ) , you have

```
>sqlite3 test.dat
SQLite version 3.13.0 2016-05-18 10:57:30

sqlite> create table test ( a integer,b integer, c integer,d float,e text, f primary key);

sqlite> .schema
CREATE TABLE test ( a integer,b integer, c integer,d float,e text, f primary key);

sqlite> .schema --indent
CREATE TABLE test(
  a integer,
  b integer,
  c integer,
  d float,
  e text,
  f primary key
);
```

Comment: Thx. Seems to be broken in my distribution but I'll have a look later.

Comment: Works fine. Maybe because I recreated the database file since?  It doesn't work for views but it's cool.

Answer (score 11):

I was looking also for a solution for this.
The commands:

```
> .header on
> .mode column
> pragma table_info('table_name');
```

Gives the ouput:

```
    cid         name        type         notnull     dflt_value  pk
----------  ----------  -----------  ----------  ----------  ----------
0           id          varchar(24)  1                       1
1           uuid        varchar(36)  1                       0
2           title       varchar(200  1                       0
3           slug        varchar(191  1                       0
```

Comment: or you could run sqlite as like: `sqlite3 --column --header`

Answer (score 4):

This command below shows **the details of all tables in a well-formatted way**:

```
.schema --indent
```

These commands below show **the details of one table in a well-formatted way**:

```
.schema --indent <table_name>
```

Or:

```
.schema <table_name> --indent
```

In addition, these commands below show **the details about ".schema"**:

```
.help .schema
```

Or:

```
.help schema
```

Then, this is how it looks like below:

```
sqlite> .help .schema 
.schema ?PATTERN?        Show the CREATE statements matching PATTERN
   Options:
      --indent             Try to pretty-print the schema
      --nosys              Omit objects whose names start with "sqlite_"
```